# Eclipse RCP 4: Adding a Popup Menu to an MPart

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, rcp, e4

I am trying to add a Popup menu for an MPart when it is right clicked, but I am having difficulty doing so. It should function the same way it did in Eclipse 3.x (Right click near the title of the view and the popup menu to detach the view/move it appears). I have added a Popup Menu with a Handled Menu Item. I assumed this would be all that is required to allow the popup menu to appear on right click, but nothing happens when I do.

I did follow Lars Vogel's tutorials, but his tutorial only shows how to add a JFace viewer to a part, and then adding the popup menu to that viewer. What is the proper way to add a popup menu when you right click on an MPart?

[image: What the MPart looks like in my Application Model]

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide! :)

EDIT: Example of what I want

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as declaring the Popup Menu in the Application.e4xmi (or fragment) you must also use the `EMenuService` in the code to register the menu with the control that you are going to right click on.

```
@Inject
EMenuService menuService;


menuService.registerContextMenu(control, "menu id");
```

Changing the menu shown when right clicking on the tab for a part is much more complex. To do this you must define a custom renderer for the `MPartStack` using a custom renderer factory (see [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) for basic details).

Your renderer can extend the standard `StackRenderer` class and override the `populateTabMenu` method.

This is an example method I use which reduces the menu to just show 'Close':

```
@Override
protected void populateTabMenu(final Menu menu, final MPart part)
{
  if (!isClosable(part))
    return;

  // Just add Close menu item and handle enabling it correctly

  final MenuItem menuItemClose = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);

  menuItemClose.setText(SWTRenderersMessages.menuClose);

  menuItemClose.addListener(SWT.Selection, this::closeSelected);

  menu.removeListener(SWT.Show, _menuListener);
  menu.addListener(SWT.Show, _menuListener);
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg, I did this in Lars Vogel's tutorial but I got the control of a JFace viewer that I created inside the MPart and used that. I am trying to set the popup menu for when you right click on the MPart itself. Is there a way to get the control for the MPart, or another way to add the popup menu to the MPart itself?

Comment: What do you mean by 'click on the MPart'? The body of the MPart is just your controls, or are you asking about something like the toolbar or the tab?

Comment: Yes, I mean when you right click near the actual title of the MPart, the tab for the MPart. For example, in the Eclipse IDE, when you right click on the Call Hierarchy tab it displays several options. I want to be able to right click on my MPart in the same way and display the Popup Menu. (Added an example image in my question)

Comment: Perfect! Is this the only way to add custom Menu Items in the renderer (through creation of Menu objects and listeners), or is there also a way to access the Popup Menu in my Application Model and set that as the menu in the renderer?

Comment: You might be able to find things using the EModelService. I just copied the way the existing code in StackRenderer worked.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I appreciate your help :)